# Actions on Google card carousel response: Images not being displayed

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

This is the response I'm sending from the webhook:

```
conv.ask(new Carousel({
    title: 'Carousel Title',
    items: {
      'AU': {
        title: 'Australia',
        subtitle: '',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://blocky-host-files.web.app/dc_graphics/au.png',
          alt: 'Australia graphic',
        }),
      },
      'CA_US': {
        title: 'Americas',
        subtitle: 'Canada / United States',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://blocky-host-files.web.app/dc_graphics/ca_us.png',
          alt: 'Canada United States graphic',
        }),
      },
      'EU': {
        title: 'Europe',
        subtitle: '',
        image: new Image({
          url: 'https://blocky-host-files.web.app/dc_graphics/eu.png',
          alt: 'Europe graphic',
        }),
      }
    }
}));
```

This is how it looks on my phone:
[image: phone screenshot]

I cannot figure out why the images aren't shown. They are not being displayed on my Google Home Hub too.

However, the Actions on Google simulator displays my images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now after moving the images to a different host (imgur).
I've used Firebase Hosting to host the images before and somehow Google couldn't get these images from it's own platform, even though they are public accessible.

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is coming due to two possible reasons:

1. There might be a problem with the platform you are using (blocky host). It is possible that this platform is not supported for displaying the carousel, Please check, if you are able to display a card in this platform. If not - then there is some problem with the platform you are are using
2. It can be due to a network issue

You can try seeing the surface capability in the request. It can help

Comment: I've fixed it. Please view my posted Answer!